# Passing props to an other component

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I am doing Nativescript with VueJs

I have a template and I want to pass some data to the next component/page.

There isn't any really explanation in how to catch the data in the next component in [the docs](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/routing/manual-routing/).

The only thing close to it is `Passing props to the modal`

So I tried that.

```
onSubmit: function (args) {
        console.log(this.searchValue);
        this.$navigateTo(choose_startpoint, {
            props: {
                hospital: this.searchValue
            }
        })
    }
```

`this.searchValue` is a value that the user entered in the searchBar

So in the other file I try to catch it like that:

```
props: ['hospital'],

template: `
<Page class="manual_input_page" actionBarHidden="true">
    <StackLayout>
        <Button class="fas btn btn-lb" text="\uf060 Kies je startpunt" @tap="$navigateBack"></Button>
        <SearchBar class="searchbar" :text="searchValue" hint="Search" textFieldBackgroundColor="white" @textChange="onTextChanged" @submit="onSubmit" />         
        <ListView class="list-group" for="items in startpoints" @itemTap="onItemTap" separatorColor="transparent">
          <v-template>
            <Label class="item" :text="items.name" /> 
          </v-template>
        </ListView>
        <Label class="bottom-info" :text="hospital"></Label>
    </StackLayout>        
</Page>
`,
```

But it is empty? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the standard Vue way of retrieving props,

```
this.$navigateTo(PageB, {
            props: {
                hello: "World!"
            }
});
```

In **PageB**

```
<template>
<Page class="page">
    <ActionBar title="PageB" class="action-bar" />
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout class="home-panel">
            <Label class="h2 description-label" :text="$props.hello" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Page>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
     props: ['hello'],
     data() {
       return {};
     }
  };
</script>
```

Here is a [Playground sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=AwmvCL&v=2).